# How can I properly update Cobbler's distro_signatures.json to support SecurityOnion?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, cobbler

I am trying to install SecurityOnion (an xubuntu 12.04 based linux distrobution) using cobbler.

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.techbar.me/cobbler-ubuntu-12-04-installation/) to get cobbler installed from source on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have also followed the instructions [here](http://www.colinmcnamara.com/setting-up-cobbler-pxe-auto-deployment-for-ubuntu-server-12-04-precise/) to configure cobbler but I am getting an error on the cobbler import step.

I am running
`cobbler import --name=securityonion --path=/media/iso --breed=ubuntu` but it fails

```
task started: 2014-03-08_110255_import
task started (id=Media import, time=Sat Mar  8 11:02:55 2014)
Found a candidate signature: breed=ubuntu, version=precise
Found a candidate signature: breed=ubuntu, version=saucy
Found a candidate signature: breed=ubuntu, version=oneiric
Found a candidate signature: breed=ubuntu, version=lucid
Found a candidate signature: breed=ubuntu, version=quantal
Found a candidate signature: breed=ubuntu, version=raring
No signature matched in /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/securityonion
!!! TASK FAILED !!!
```

I assume this is because I need to add a signature to `/var/lib/cobbler/distro_signatures.json`

I know I should be able to copy and paste the definition for precise and make it work since SecurityOnion uses 12.04 but I don't know how to change the definition so that it matches whatever string of text I assume cobbler is looking for under the installation files that make up securityonion.

I have read the [documentation](http://www.cobblerd.org/manuals/2.4.0/4/2/3_-_Distro_Signatures.html) on cobbler site but it doesn't seem to give me what I need to be able to add an additional distribution.

Anyone know what I can do to modify the signatures file to accept this additional distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Cobbler will download the latest 'update' distro_signatures.json using the command below:

```
# cobbler signature update
```

Comment: I am not looking to download the latest version but to author a new version by adding a new signature to the file.

Comment: Since it is Ubuntu based -- wouldn't you use Ubuntu as the signature?  For  instance both Fedora and RHEL fall under the Red Hat signature. http://cobbler.github.io/manuals/2.4.0/4/2/3_-_Distro_Signatures.html